# resizing an imagebutton programmatically to keep it square

Tags: java, android, height, android-linearlayout

I am working on a project and my challenge is with getting the `ImageButtons` to be square shaped. I am using `LinearLayouts`, so I used `layout_weight` for the width so that the width of the screen can be distributed equally among the `ImageButtons`, and a preset `layout_height` of `"100dp"`. I want to now programmatically change the `layout_height` to the allocated `layout_width`. I have checked other questions but none does what I am looking for. Please help.
Here is the `activity_main.xml`file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.abdul.sdgschampoins.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal1"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal2"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal3"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal4"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal5"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal6"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal7"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal8"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal9"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal9"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal10"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal10"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal11"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal11"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal12"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal12"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal13"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal13"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal14"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal14"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal15"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal15"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal16"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal16"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goal17"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/goal17"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/dummyIcon"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/sdglogo"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this :

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(button.getWidth(), button.getWidth());
```

Comment: I tried that and the `ImageButton` I tried it on disappeared from the screen.